# Best approach to a particular matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find the matrix $X$ knowing that $(A - 2In)^{-1}X = 2X + B$

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 2\\
         3 & 4
        \end{bmatrix}$ and B = $\begin{bmatrix}
         1\\
         -1
        \end{bmatrix}$

I'm here looking if it can be reduced to something like $AX = B$ then $X = A^{-1}B$ but there'are $X$ on both sides, and whenever i transform it, falls into the same thing ($X$ on both sides). I don't work with matrices much times, so...

I'm also using the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} a & b\\c & d \end{bmatrix}$ as $X$ for the left side but it's too slow and takes lot of time.

**Note:** i'm actually using a $3{\times}3$ matrices for a and $3{\times}1$ for B

Comment: lf $X$ is $3 \times 3$ and $B$ is $3 \times 1$, the right hands side doesn't make sense.  How are we to perform the indicated addition?

Comment: Is the $n$ intended ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's 3, my bad.

Comment: @Edilson: no, you don't get my remark.

Comment: @RobertLewis i'm ending with multiple equations systems doing like this, let me check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
(A-2I)^{-1} X &= 2 X + B
\\
((A-2I)^{-1} - 2I)X &= B
\\
X &= ((A-2I)^{-1} - 2I)^{-1} B
\end{align}

Comment: My bean sized brain, the inverse itself, thanks for this, i was thinking about division which is not possible then forgot that i could just invert.

Answer (score 1):

$$(A-2I)^{-1}X=2X+B$$ so that
$$IX=(A-2I)(2X+B)=2(A-2I)X+(A-2I)B$$
and
$$(I-2A+4I)X=(5I-2A)X=(A-2I)B,$$

$$X=(5I-2A)^{-1}(A-2I)B.$$